# When connecting directly to modem, Public Ip is different

Tags: networking, router, modem

There are frequent periods of time where I have to connect directly to my Modem, and periods of time when I use my Router in-between connections. I also frequently use RDC to connect to my computer. I have noticed that, depending on which configuration I am using, I have a different static IP address. This is always the same, depending on what I'm plugged in to.

Example:
Direct To Modem : x.x.x.205
Through Router  : x.x.x.250

Has my ISP given me multiple IP addresses, and (Looking from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/707463/if-you-connect-directly-to-your-modem-how-does-the-ip-address-get-assigned)) is my Computer DHCP Interpreting that in a different way than my Router does?

Comment: How did you check the IP if you're connect through your router? It might be that one is a private IP and the other your public one. In addition, depending on the frequency of your changes, you might have two independent "leases" for those IPs.

Comment: Yup, depending on your setup it could various things, but most likely - two independent leases. But seems the main problem is you are thinking about some network concepts a bit unclearly. `static` address is not given by DHCP server - it is what you set your computer to be. Your ISP probably has given one `external` IP - the one with which your modem is facing the world. That could change from time to time as your modem reboots, etc. Unlikely scenario is if your ISP is giving you `external` IP addresses assigned via DHCP (but only in that case it makes sense to mask octets as x.x.x...).

Comment: @Seth I'm fairly familiar with the concept of private IP's and Public IP's. These are public IP's. I use them to connect with Remote Desktop.

Comment: You didn't provide the information so it was a valid assumption. Why are there periods where you need to directly connect instead of using your router? If you're using your router it would be strange to get an internet IP on your computer and your DHCP shouldn't have anything to do with it. To be certain you would likely have to connect your ISP and ask them whenever there are two devices registered for your connection or similar.